# Calculate average from multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

[image: Example Table]

To produce a useful Line Graph, out of a set of "time increments", I converted said increments to seconds and rounded the values.

The image showcases this with a table of column-A: *time increments*, column-B: `=ROUND(A2/1000000; 0)` filled down, and column-D: *points* *(for example)*.

---

Column-B, if rounded, has lots of non-unique values, which may be averaged to a single row *(I prefer averaging over distracting)*.

**What I tried:**
Due to little experience in Excel, I tried copying column-B by value to a new column *(to avoid errors when removing rows)*, then filter by unique values, and copy the sets to a new sheet, to then proceed creating a graph with less values for improved readability.

---

Having filtered by `Unique records only` from `Data > Filter, Advanced`, I selected column-D and generated a Line Graph, without having to edit the horizontal-axis, due to the time increments being in sequence.

However, this method is definitely slow and not viable when having to do this often. Any suggestion is very much appreciated!

Comment: are you sure you want a line graph and not a scatter plot?  a line graph will ignore porportional spacing between X axis values and instead spaces them apart equally regard if one set is one second apart and the next is 1000 seconds apart.

Comment: (1) Please post text (data) as text, not as an image. (2) If you have nearly 40 000 rows of data, that’s probably worth mentioning. But do you have to show us a data sample from Rows 38 796 - 38 834? I doubt it. That just makes it harder to read. (3) Likewise, please don’t post more than 15 or 20 rows of data unless you really need to. (4) What is Column D? The data that you want to chart on the “Y” axis? (5) Please be explicit about what result you want. If you can create something that looks like the chart you want, that would be a good thing to post as an image. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (Although you should also *describe* it *in words.*) (6) I feel like you should either say more or less about what your data set represents. For example, what is Column A? Microseconds? (We can’t read your mind.) It seems to me that you could just hide Column A and present the problem in terms of Columns B and D. (7) This is nit-picking, but, if Column B can, by definition, contain only integers, why are you displaying two decimal digits (always ``00``)? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: POC]

off to the side in a column you are not using list your seconds.  Lets say the first cell is F1.  Seed your list with the following formula:

```
=MIN(B:B)
```

It will pull your lowest second.  Once you have the start of your list, use the following formula in F2 and copy down until it is producing cells with "" in them.

=IF(OR(F1=MAX(B:B),F1=""),"",F1+1)

It checks to see when you have reached the maximum value in the previous cell and places a "" in it.  It will also do that if there previous cell is equal to "".  Otherwise it increases the value of the previous cell by 1.

In G1 get the average value for in column C for all seconds matching what is in F1.  Use the following formula for G1 and copy down to the bottom of your list in column G.

```
=AVERAGEIF(B:B,F1,C:C)
```

NOTE my system uses `,` as a separateor instead of `;`. you will need adjust the formulas to match your system.

Comment: Solid answer. I tried the `averageif` method and it works wonders, thanks.